# masking UIImageView when it leaves the UIViewController's frame

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an Advertisement UIViewController class that contains the following code. The frame is the exact dimension of the image. When it animates down I want it to disappear at the 76.0 point. I made the UIViewController's frame the same size as the image too, but it doesn't obscure any of the image when it slides down.

How do I make it so that I cannot see the uiimageview when it leaves the UIViewController frame?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{


    UIImageView *ad = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 76.0)];
    ad.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"advertisement.jpg"];

    [self.view addSubview:ad];
    [ad release];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0    //animate the content offset
                          delay:6.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         ad.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 152.0, 320.0, 76.0);                   }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }

     ];




}
```

Appdelegate:

```
Advertisement *theAdView = [[Advertisement alloc] init];
    theAdView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.window.frame.size.height-120.0, 320.0, 76.0);
    [self.window addSubview:theAdView.view];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `clipsToBounds` property on the view (of the viewcontroller) to YES. Subviews of the view will then be drawn only within the bounds of the view.

[UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)